# Encountering Weasels in the Wild in Scotland

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, scotland

I understand that it's possible, but difficult, to visit [Scotland and see weasels](http://www.wildlifebritain.com/stoatorweasel.php) in the wild and I'm interested in this. I would need to use Scotland's '[Right to Roam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam)' rules because I don't know anyone with substantial amounts of property there.

Is there a particular 'Right to Roam' trail where the chances of observing a weasel, possibly even a weasel family, might be higher than another trail?   Or are the trails generally the same with respect to spotting a weasel?

I understand that one must sit very still in an isolated location and wait for a long time before a weasel will pass by, and that overall it's a matter of luck. Is there anything that can be done to improve the chances? I considered bringing some dog treats but then worried that it's probably against the rules.  Also is there anything else that can be done so as not to disrupt the other wildlife that may be using the area?

It would be great to select a spot where I could observe both a weasel and a seal (a view over the water). Is there a 'Right to Roam' vantage point that offers that possibility? It's not an 'outdoors' question, it's more about nature along with what can be seen and where.

**Question**: what's the range of weasel varieties in Scotland? Where are they most likely to be seen? Does time of day may any difference?

Comment: See also http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza

Comment: Instead of just waiting for a weasel you could search the home of a weasel. And wait there. And before, try to find a ranger, hunter or any other local people who could know where to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of anywhere that you're specifically more likely to see weasels (outside of zoos and wildlife parks), but there's a load of hill and paths you can go on with a chance of seeing them.

In Scotland you can pretty much go anywhere (apart from people's gardens) but I'd recommend sticking to established paths (there are loads of these all over the country).

In terms of seeing one in the wild, I've got to say I think your chances are fairly low.  I walk in Argyll every day pretty much and I've seen maybe one or two cross my path in the last 3 years.

Larger mustalids (e.g. Pine Martens) are somewhat easier to come across in that they'll come to places where they get fed, although even then they're not exactly regular.

One recommendation I would have is that you might have more chance of seeing this kind of wildlife on a ranger guided tour somewhere like [Aigas](http://www.aigas.co.uk/)